# The proper way to retrieve a sorted set from Redis using BookSleeve

Tags: c#, .net, date, booksleeve

As per [some suggestions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14446531/how-to-save-and-retrieve-channel-data-from-redis-pub-sub-with-date-ranges), I am using Redis' `ZADD` through BookSleeve's `SortedSets.Add()` to save data in a chronological order as follows:

```
TimeSpan span = DateTime.UtcNow.Subtract(new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0)); 
_connection.SortedSets.Add(_db, thisChannel, message, span.TotalSeconds, false);
```

Using ServiceStack's AdminUI, I can see the values tucked away in Redis.

The values are stored as UTC, and I would now like to be able to get return a range of values.

Simply, since I saved the values recently, I tried:

```
var subset = _connection.Wait(_connection.SortedSets.Range(_db, thisChannel, span.TotalSeconds - 10000, span.TotalSeconds, offset: 0, count: 50));
```

In VS, the collection contains the double value, and the Key which is of type Byte[].  I assume this is the byte array of the data saved - even though I saved it as string?

I have reviewed some code [here](https://code.google.com/r/tobias-booksleeve/source/browse/Tests/SortedSets.cs?spec=svn3c4ab6a659ea1cfc89102fb6ac8eae87744285d5&r=3c4ab6a659ea1cfc89102fb6ac8eae87744285d5) and would like to know if there extensive documentation and some samples on how to use this function?

Comment: Booksleeve acts basically as a shim directly on top of the [underlying ZRANGE command](http://redis.io/commands/zrange); btw the most direct tests link is [here](https://code.google.com/p/booksleeve/source/browse/Tests/SortedSets.cs). The `byte[]` coming back is just UTF-8 encoded - there is also `RangeString` which does the translation for you. I have to go and get food "now", but I can come back later to add a more complete example. Can you clarify: what is the issue currently? are you not getting the expected rows? or is it simply a case of switching to `RangeString`? how can I help?

Comment: Reading the ZRANGE documentation, I see that the start/stop values are zero-based beginning to end of the given range.  So when I'm using RangeString() I use 0, 99999 (as no out of range exceptions are thrown) I would expect the full range of items.  However, I consistently get "The method or operation is not implemented" error" .  Also, not using the score doesn't help me in this case (as the score is the timestamp) and I use this for range gets.

Comment: that's interesting, and there was no way I could have deduced that from the question! Is there a stacktrace for that? I'm going to spin up a quick test to see if I can repro that with your code

Answer (score 0):

The interesting thing I noticed in this is that `RangeString`, which should be ideal for your scenario, lacks the `offset` parameter; I will rectify that - but for now, we can use `Range` and decode the key manually (redis allows binary keys; they do not need to be strings); the following, however, passes successfully:

```
[Test]
public void SO14991819()
{
    const int _db = 0;
    const string thisChannel = "SO14991819";
    const string message = "hi";
    using (var _connection = Config.GetUnsecuredConnection())
    {
        _connection.Keys.Remove(_db, thisChannel); // start from known state

        TimeSpan span = DateTime.UtcNow.Subtract(new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0));
        double val = span.TotalSeconds;

        _connection.SortedSets.Add(_db, thisChannel, message, val, false);

        var subset = _connection.Wait(_connection.SortedSets.Range(
            _db, thisChannel, span.TotalSeconds - 10000, span.TotalSeconds, offset: 0, count: 50));

        Assert.AreEqual(1, subset.Length);
        Config.AssertNearlyEqual(val, subset[0].Value);
        Assert.AreEqual(message, Encoding.UTF8.GetString(subset[0].Key));
    }
}
```

I certainly don't get a `MethodNotImplementedException`. I should state: I'm testing against the current "head", simply because that is what I have available.

---

For info: in my local copy I've implemented `RangeString` with offset/count, so the following passes:

```
var subset = _connection.Wait(_connection.SortedSets.RangeString(
    _db, thisChannel, span.TotalSeconds - 10000, span.TotalSeconds, offset: 0, count: 50));

Assert.AreEqual(1, subset.Length);
Config.AssertNearlyEqual(val, subset[0].Value);
Assert.AreEqual(message, subset[0].Key);
```

Comment: I added String.Format("urn:{0}", thisChannel) - thus a fully qualified key.

Comment: @ElHaix a key is a key is a key; redis doesn't care what the contents are. I changed my key with `string.Format` - it still works fine. Can you show me a repro of the problem you are having? Incidentally: I see absolutely no benefit adding a `"urn:"` prefix here...